# Emacsclients locks up on mini-buffer use

Tags: emacsclient, minibuffer

If you start `emacs --daemon -q` and then connect two `emacsclients` to it. If you press `C-x C-f` or anything that activates the minibuffer - no input to the other emacsclients will be accepted until that minibuffer is closed.

Is it possible to prevent this from happening?

Comment: In my experience this only happens when a terminal client is involved; so yes, you can stop it from happening by using GUI clients.

Comment: @phils True, graphical emacsclients don't prevent input to the buffer but seem to share minibuffer so that one cannot for example run `M-x` in two different clients at the same time.

Comment: Yes -- there is only one minibuffer (unless you enable *recursive* minibuffers, but that's unrelated to client/server functionality, and doesn't achieve what you're asking for).